# Programmatically Monitoring SQL Server 2005 mirror

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, monitoring, database-mirroring

Does SQL Server 2005 provide an interface that can be programmatically addressed to determine the health of a mirrored database?

If so, does anyone have examples of how to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For monitoring, querying the sys.database_mirroring DMV is probably the easiest. It contains fields for mirroring_role_desc and mirroring_state_desc.

Link to BOL: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178655.aspx

The SQL Error log also provides information about these, and there is an event you can catch with SQL Trace as well, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

This video tutorial can give some inputs for your requirement

Video - How to setup Database(DB) Mirroring SQL Server 2005 Tutorial
URL - http://wtv.watchtechvideos.com/topic275.html